# Python Pandas export to csv not correctly handling escaping

Tags: python, pandas, escaping, export-to-csv

I have the following problem: i read a csv with the following sequence
`\"\\\"`
which pandas reads correctly (because if i print the dataframe it outputs `"\"`. But if i now export the dataframe again to csv it will give me the character sequence `\"\\"` which is not working in the software the exported csv gets used in.

The settings I use to read the csv:

```
import = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep="|", dtype=str, quotechar='"', escapechar="\\")
```

Export settings:

```
import.to_csv('export.csv', sep="|", index=False, encoding='utf-8', escapechar="\\", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, doublequote=False)
```

This gives me for everything else I have correct results.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Don't think you need that `doublequote=False` there...

Comment: If I don't set that option it will double quote everything (so for example `""something""` instead of `\"something\"`) which is not my intended behaviour